# Django Admin doesn't recognize files uploaded on Google App Engine

Tags: django, google-app-engine, django-nonrel

I am using Django 1.4 on Google App Engine.

I have a model called Media, where the admins can upload files to use in their website. It has a field:

```
file = models.FileField(upload_to='/uploads/%Y/%m/%d')
```

It works perfectly with images (although the URL provided is *weird*), but that is not a problem.

The problem is when they try to upload a PDF (or anything else). Everything seems to work, but when you go to edit it, it doesn't contain any file - there is no "Currently" or anything else.

If I go to Google App Engine dashboard, the file is in Blob Viewer, and the record is also saved and available through the Datastore Viewer, with the correct blob key.

Why Django is not recognizing it? And how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1):

djangoappengine contains a storage provider for the blobstore.

To me it doesn't seem like a full-featured solution, just something to get file uploads running.

I had to add this to get some functionality I needed (urls to the files).
It might make the admin work too:

https://github.com/dragonx/djangoappengine/commit/6a472a80c25bc077816c9104b45d5a64f3063273